# Font Awesome icons not showing: fa-podcast

Tags: html, font-awesome

I have a basic SpringBoot app., embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.
I have this piece of code in my HTML page, there is 1 Font Awesome icon that does not show up (the second: **fa fa-podcast**)

```
 <!-- Start Menu -->
            <ul class="pure-menu-list">
                <li class="pure-menu-title">Start</li>

                 <li class="menu-principal pure-menu-item pure-menu-selected">
                    <a href="/tdk/deviceevent/list" class="pure-menu-link">
                        <i class="fa fa-mixcloud fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; A
                    </a>
                </li>

                 <li class="menu-principal pure-menu-item">
                    <a href="/tdk/device/list" class="pure-menu-link">
                        <i class="fa fa-podcast fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; B
                    </a>
                </li>            

                <li class="menu-principal pure-menu-item ">
                     <a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">
                        <i class="fa fa-truck fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; C
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-principal pure-menu-item">
                     <a href="/tdk/timeLapse/list" class="pure-menu-link">
                        <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; D
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="menu-principal pure-menu-item">
                     <a href="/tdk/alarmNotification/list" class="pure-menu-link">
                        <i class="fa fa-flag fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; E
                    </a>
                </li>

                 <li class="menu-principal pure-menu-item">
                    <a href="/tdk/guardian/list" class="pure-menu-link">
                       <i class="fa fa-shield fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; F
                   </a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-principal pure-menu-item">
                    <a href="/tdk/applicationSetup" class="pure-menu-link"><i class="fa fa-cogs fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; G</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-principal pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link"><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; H</a></li>      
               <!--  <li class="menu-principal pure-menu-item">
                    <a href="#" class="pure-menu-link"><i class="fa fa-tv fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; I</a>
                </li> -->
                <li class="menu-principal pure-menu-item">
                    <a href="#" class="pure-menu-link"><i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Help</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue seems to be with the fa-podcast only.   I have the 4.7 library running and the fa class ahead of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what version of font-awesome library do you have  ?? 
make sure you have the latest version downloaded and you will be fine 
if you want to check if fa-podcast check the version it is introduced in 
[image]

so you need to have font awesome version > 4.7